# How to use require('xyz") in Ionic2 typescript

Tags: ionic2, nwjs

I am currently working on Ionic2 + nw.js app.

I have created the Ionic2 part, but I have to use nw.js api. For that I have to use

```
var gui = require('nw.gui');
var path = require('path');
```

Ionic2 typescript compiler gives error in require('xyz') statement. Is there is any way to bypass typescript compiler error for this.

I have used at the top:

```
declare var gui:any;
```

but no benefit.

Currently I have to use workaround where I create the Ionic2 app and later edit app.bundle.js for NW.js integration.

Comment: `import gui = require(...)`?

Comment: @ jonrsharpe , import gui = require(...) is not working as nw.exe is not available during ionic2 development. After using 'ionic serve', I am copying 'www' folder inside the nw.exe folder.